# scrapy does not follow all URLs within a page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and just successfully crawled a page, retrieving 58 results while I was looking for 120 results that are available.

The problem seems to be, that if one website contains 4 links, scrapy follows the first one and the other three will never be visited as the links to those pages are only within that one page and it will never be visited again. I am assuming this, since within the result set those 3 are missing but the links are OK if I visit the page in the browser.

The spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

#CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT=1

from bid.items import riegerItem

class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.co.uk/']

    rules = (

        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['test/.*,item,.*u']), 
            callback='parse_item'
        ),

        # follow all urls in beta folder that are not schmuck
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['test/[^dismiss|this].*']), 
            follow=True
        ),
    )
    ...
```

Output:

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 31681,
 'downloader/request_count': 101,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 101,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1129752,
 'downloader/response_count': 101,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 101,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 746,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 22, 23, 0, 30, 937420),
 'item_scraped_count': 58,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 161,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'memusage/max': 49242112,
 'memusage/startup': 49242112,
 'request_depth_max': 4,
 'response_received_count': 101,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 100,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 100,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 100,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 100,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 22, 23, 0, 26, 78036)}
2018-11-23 00:00:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I am using the default settings from the template spider.

If I run it again, slightly other amounts will be fetched

How can I debug this problem in order to retrieve all results?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The regex with the second rule was prohibiting those URLs. Worked on the regex and not it runs OK.